# Debian, Register Programming

Tags: c, debian, embedded-linux, hardware

I have an A20 Olimex Board running on Debian and I would like to use the ADC. As I figured out I have to write or read the respective registers of the ADC. Could somebody tell me shortly how to do that?

I am really new in Linux.

Comment: You have any board documentation ? If yes, start digging there, if no you better find some

Comment: If the ADC is an integrated peripheral of the Allwinner A20 SoC, then the salient documentation to study would be the SoC's datasheet and/or [user manual](http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/A20/A20%20User%20Manual%20V1.20.pdf).

Comment: The user manuel tells about the register values to perform the task, but it doesn't say how to set them. I am sure I can't just use the register name as an identifier as I do when programming a controller. But I just saw the Base Adress entry and the Offsets on page 139. So I guess I have to point to the memory adress and use the offset. I think I will be able to do that. But maybe somebody has some good advice for me to avoid common mistakes? Or somebody could confirm my understanding?